# LTS: How to test behavior dependent on afterScriptsLoaded

Tags: lightning-testing-service

I’m looking for help/examples for setting up tests of a component which calls a `load()` method via `afterScriptsLoaded`, then renders data based on the result of the load (which calls a server-side controller) — something like this.

Component:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.Constants,$Resource.Utils)}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.load}"/>

<aura:attribute name="currencyOptions" type="OppActionOverrideController.CurrencyOption[]" description="List of currency options with user's preferred currency set to default"/>
<aura:attribute name="someOtherThing" type="String" description="This is just an example of something else to render"/>

<aura:attribute name="showCurrencyField" type="Boolean" default="false" description="Value set in the load() callback"/>
<aura:attribute name="showSomeOtherField" type="Boolean" default="false" description="Value set in the load() callback"/>

<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showCurrencyField}">
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectedCurrency" label="Currency" required="true">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.currencyOptions}" var="curr">
                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!curr.isoCode}" label="{!curr.isoCode}" value="{!curr.isDefault}"/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ui:inputSelect>
        </div>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSomeOtherField}">
        <div aura:id="someOtherField">foobar</div>
    </aura:if>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
load: function (component, event, handler) {
    var action = component.get("c.getComponentData");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        // ....do some validation, if response is successful....

        // set up currency options
        component.set('v.showCurrencyField', true);
        component.set('v.currencyOptions', currencyOptions);

        // set other things
        component.set('v.showSomeOtherField', true);
        component.set('v.someOtherThing', 'hello');
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Test suite:

```
afterEach(function() {
    $T.clearRenderedTestComponents();
});

describe("Rendering the component", function() {
    var getComponentDataPayload = {
        currencyOptions: [
            {isoCode: "USD", isDefault: true},
            {isoCode: "EUR", isDefault: false},
            {isoCode: "GBP", isDefault: false},
        ]
    };
    var renderedComponent = null;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        renderedComponent = null;

        $T.createComponent("c:MyComponent", {}, true)
        .then(function(component) {
            // I assign the component to a separate var so that it can be referenced in specs below, allows me to use a beforeEach instead of having this code in every spec
            renderedComponent = component;

            spyOn($A, "enqueueAction").and.callFake(function(action) {
                var callback = action.getCallback("SUCCESS");
                // The utility function here just takes the payload data and wraps it with the proper getState() and getReturnValue(), etc.
                callback.fn.apply(callback.s, [TestUtils.getMockedServerActionResult(true, "", getComponentDataPayload)]);
                done();
            });
        }).catch(funtion(e) {
            done.fail(e);
        });
    });

    it("renders the currency options", function(done) {
        expect(renderedComponent.find("selectedCurrency")).toBeDefined();
        done();
    });

    it("renders some other field", function(done) {
        expect(renderedComponent.find("someOtherField")).toBeDefined();
        done();
    });
});
```

The specific problem I’m struggling with is where to place the `spyOn` (either inside the `createComponent` callback as above, or before it, or elsewhere) and also where to call `done()` in the `beforeEach`. The way the example is defined above, the first spec passes. But when the second spec runs, the scripts are already loaded, so that `load()` call happens immediately, before the `createComponent` callback happens (and so the spy is not registered and the `done()` function inside it is never called). I’ve tried moving the spy outside of the `createComponent` callback and calling `done()` in different places, but each results in a condition where either the `renderedComponent` var is not defined by the time `done()` is called (and thus the specs fail) or the `done()` method is never called due to the order that things execute the second time through and I get a timeout.

Is there a better way to structure this spec so that the order of the `load` call in relation to when the component is done rendering can be more predictable? I prefer to keep my `it` blocks simple and re-render the component each time, and re-rendering the component with different data to test conditional display is required for this test.

UPDATE
After experimenting a bit more I've tried modifying the structure of the beforeEach to this:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    renderedComponent = null;

    spyOn($A, "enqueueAction").and.callFake(function(action) {
        var callback = action.getCallback("SUCCESS");
        // The utility function here just takes the payload data and wraps it with the proper getState() and getReturnValue(), etc.
        callback.fn.apply(callback.s, [TestUtils.getMockedServerActionResult(true, "", getComponentDataPayload)]);
    });

    $T.createComponent("c:MyComponent", {}, true)
    .then(function(component) {
        // I assign the component to a separate var so that it can be referenced in specs below, allows me to use a beforeEach instead of having this code in every spec
        renderedComponent = component;

        return $T.waitFor(function() {
            return renderedComponent.find("selectedCurrency") !== undefined;
        });
    }).then(function() {
        done();
    }).catch(function(e) {
        done.fail(e);
    });
});
```

To summarize the difference from the above version, this moves registering the spy out of the `createComponent` callback, which ensures it always happens. Then I am using a bit of a hack with `waitFor` to make sure the pieces of the component under test have indeed been rendered before testing them. This seems to result in a consistent order of operations, but now I am seeing timeouts (using the LTS-defined 3s) with the `$T.createComponent`, but *only when running three or more specs*. The first two specs run quickly and without a problem.

I'm hoping that I'm missing something obvious with this setup, does anyone have any ideas or examples of doing something similar?